# Failed on Trying to fetch JSON object using XMLHttpRequest and resulted in empty quotation

Tags: javascript, json, functional-programming, xmlhttprequest, fetch

I'm trying to Fetch and Parse JSON-Object using XMLHttpRequest in Javascript but it always fail and results in empty quotation...

```
            function getJSON(target = null)
            {
                var response_data = [];
                var target_url = target;
                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.open('GET', target_url, true);
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
                xhr.send();
                xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function ()
                {
                  if(xhr.readyState === 4)
                  {
                     if(xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 304)
                     {
                        response_data += xhr.response;
                     }
                     else
                     {
                        response_data += $.getJSON(target_url);
                        console.log('[XHR-DEBUG]: Unexpected HTTP response code: ' + xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText + '(' + target_url + ')');            
                     }
                  }
                });
                return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify((typeof response_data === 'undefined' || response_data === null || response_data.toString().split(',').length <= 1 ? xhr.response : response_data)));
            }
```

Usage:

```
   getJSON('localhost/logs.json');
```

Expected result:

```
   ["John eaten the cake","Stackoverflow is awesome"]
```

Current result:

```
   ""
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used asynchronous `XMLHttpRequest`. So the problem is at the following line:

```
return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify((typeof response_data === 'undefined' || response_data === null || response_data.toString().split(',').length <= 1 ? xhr.response : response_data)));
```

This is placed outside the event listener  and data isn't avaible when that line runs.

To make it working, use synchronous `XMLHttpRequest` (not recommended):

```
xhr.open('GET',target_url,false)
```

Or use async/await:

```
async function getJSON(target = null)
    {
        var response_data = [];
        var target_url = target;
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', target_url, true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        await new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
            xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function ()
            {
              if(xhr.readyState === 4)
              {
                 if(xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 304)
                 {
                    response_data.push(xhr.response);
                 }
                 else
                 {
                    response_data.push(await getJSON(target_url));
                    console.log('[XHR-DEBUG]: Unexpected HTTP response code: ' + xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText + '(' + target_url + ')');            
                 }
                 resolve()
              }
            });
            xhr.send()
        });
        return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify((typeof response_data === 'undefined' || response_data === null || response_data.length <= 1 )? xhr.response : response_data));
    }
```

See also:

[Async function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)
[Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)
[Await operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)

I hope that this will help you!